# How is it possible for a Netsuite Workflow to visit previous states?

Tags: netsuite

I have a workflow with four states

1. Initiation
2. Quote
3. Approved
4. Closed (end state)

There are transitions from 1->2, 2->3, 3->4. I have "do not exit end state" enabled so that it is not possible for a record to enter the workflow twice.

The thing I cannot understand is that in some situations, according to the workflow history, the record moves back to previous states - see the image below from workflow history with columns "State Name Info", "Date Entered State" and "Date Exited State". Note that there is e.g an "Approved" state entry at 5:33pm which is after the workflow entered the closed state for the first time at 5:32pm, even though there is no transition from Closed to Approved
[image]

How is this possible and what could be causing it?

Some details that might be relevant:

- The workflow has a workflow script action in the Approved state that calls a Suitelet
- There is a User Event script that applies to the record (Sales Order)

Answer (score 0):

I've had something similar happen when there's an error in the action that is being transitioned in to, for example, performing a  "Send email" action on entry to the action, and sending it to an invalid recipient.

Comment: This post doesn't look like an attempt to answer this question. Every post here is expected to be an explicit attempt to *answer* this question; if you have a critique or need a clarification of the question or another answer, you can [post a comment](/help/privileges/comment) (like this one) directly below it. Please remove this answer and create either a comment or a new question. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour)

Comment: I have also seen bad things happen when a workflow action fails, but I don't think that was causing the problem in this case since there were no workflow action failures in the workflow history logs.

Answer (score 0):

From the initial analysis, it looks like the workflow action script which calls the suitelet and user event script that could be the cause of these transitions. On the workflow, you mentioned that there are no direct transitions from "Approved" to "Closed State". Could you please paste the contents of the workflow action script for further analysis on the issue

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour)

Comment: I have pointed out where the issue lies, since it's not on the workflow. To completely analyze the root cause, additional information is required which is what I have added on my post. The cause of the lies in the customizations related to the workflow

Comment: You are right that the workflow action script was contributing to the issue by adding another a suitelet context under which workflow transitions would execute, however disabling the workflow action script didn't prevent the unexpected status transitions.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by multiple processes triggering the workflow transitions simultaneously. There were no errors in the workflow actions reported using logging, but I could see that there were different contexts for transition in the different duplicated workflow states in Workflow History.

I resolved the problem by tightening up the context under which the transitions would run. I set:

- All transitions to afterSubmit (previously this was blank, which I think means that transition will be attempted in beforeLoad, beforeSubmit and afterSubmit)
- Context for transitions to just the the two contexts I want to trigger transitions: SOAP Web Services and User Interface